# EPPlus dates FORMAT gengerated properly

Tags: c#, epplus

I have a problem with date  format, I have a generic class that reads property and property type.
EPPlus generates for a date column the good format but the other it is not.

```
public class ExcelHelper
{
    public static byte[] GenerateXls<T>(List<T> dataSource, string sheetName)
    {

        using (var pck = new ExcelPackage())
        {

            var modelProperties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
            Type typeNullDatetime = typeof(DateTime?);
            Type typeDateTime = typeof(DateTime);
            Type typeDecimal = typeof(decimal);
            Type typeNullDecimal = typeof(decimal?);
            var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(sheetName);
            ws.Cells[1, 1].LoadFromCollection(dataSource, true, OfficeOpenXml.Table.TableStyles.Light1);


            for (var j = 0; j < modelProperties.Length; j++)
            {
                if (modelProperties[j].PropertyType == typeNullDatetime
                        && DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo != null)
                    ws.Column(j).Style.Numberformat.Format =
                        DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.ShortDatePattern;

                if (modelProperties[j].PropertyType == typeDateTime)
                    if (DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo != null)
                        ws.Column(j).Style.Numberformat.Format =
                            DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.ShortDatePattern;

                if (modelProperties[j].PropertyType == typeDecimal)
                    ws.Column(j).Style.Numberformat.Format = "0.00";

                if (modelProperties[j].PropertyType == typeNullDecimal)
                    ws.Column(j).Style.Numberformat.Format = "0.00";
            }

            ws.Cells.AutoFitColumns();
            return pck.GetAsByteArray();

        }

    }
}
```

```
var result = ExcelHelper.GenerateXls(dtos, "data");
```

the genertated excel for a class containing these two properties :

```
  public DateTime IssueDate { get; set; }
  public DateTime DeadlineDate { get; set; }
```

```
Issue Date  Deadline Date
25/06/2019  43641
25/06/2019  43641
05/06/2019  43622
27/05/2019  43612
24/04/2019  43579
15/04/2019  43570
```

Comment: Let me guess, Issue Date and Deadline Date are not exactly same type am I right? I would say one of them is nullable.

Comment: public DateTime IssueDate { get; set; }
  public DateTime DeadlineDate { get; set; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In EPPlus column and rows are **not zero-based** indices but 1-based. So the first column of the first row has Row=1 and Column=1.
 you need to change the loop like below

```cs
...
for (var j = 1; j <= modelProperties.Length; j++)
...
```

or

```cs
...
ws.Column(j+1)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when wanting to format columns dynamically base on a given Type. I came up with a solution that takes care of null type checking. You can of course set the number format (and other styles) to whatever you like. I hope it helps!

```
public static void FormatColumns<T>(ExcelWorksheet sheet)
{
    var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        var columnIndex = Array.IndexOf(properties, property) + 1; //Since it is not zero based
        var type = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(property.PropertyType) ?? property.PropertyType; // Checks if it's a nullable
        var typeCode = Type.GetTypeCode(type);
        FormatRange(sheet.Column(columnIndex), typeCode);
    }
}
public static void FormatRange(ExcelColumn range, TypeCode typeCode)
{
    switch (typeCode)
    {
        case TypeCode.Int32:
            range.Style.Numberformat.Format = "General";
            break;
        case TypeCode.Double:
            range.Style.Numberformat.Format = "_(* #,##0.00_);_(* (#,##0.00);_(* \" - \"??_);_(@_)";
            break;
        case TypeCode.Decimal:
            range.Style.Numberformat.Format = "_ * #,##0.00_ ;[red]_ * -#,##0.00_ ;_ * \"-\"??_ ;_ @_ ";
            break;
        case TypeCode.DateTime:
            range.Style.Numberformat.Format = "dd-MMM-yy";
            break;
        default:
            range.Style.Numberformat.Format = "General";
            break;
    }
}
```